# Virtual machine for safe browsing and Firefox account

Tags: firefox, security, virtual-machine, linux-mint, vmware

I've set a virtual machine (with VMware) running Linux Mint to browse potentially unsafe sites with Firefox. Should I sign in with my Firefox account there or I'll be at risk?

Comment: You are using a VM, I assume so if it get's infected, you can discard the changes and start over.  If you logged into an account, and the account's credentials are harvested, you can't reset that.

Comment: If you get malware whilst logged with the Firefox account chances are it'll be synced to the other Firefox instances. You may even not notice it in Linux (not designed to run on Linux) but you will once synced to your (Windows) Firefox.